# Ugrading to the latest CU, do I need to apply all CU's?

Tags: 2013, administration, upgrade, cumulative-update

I have SharePoint server 2013, with the following build number:

```
 15.0.4481.1005
```

I want to install the latest updates, where the host server is not connected to the internet. So I need to manually download the CU.

But on [this link](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346) it is mentioned that I am missing a lot of CU, so my question is weather installing the latest CU will be enough ? Or will I need to install the missing CU one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Service Pack 1 and the September 2014 CU if you want the latest fixes and updates. You do not need to install any previous CU.